# Passing parameters to a url

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jax-rs

I'm calling a jsp page through an jax-rs endpoint as below.

```
 public String logout(@Context HttpServletRequest request,@DefaultValue("Empty Details") @QueryParam("logoutNotification") String logoutNotification,
                     @QueryParam("id_token_hint") String id_token_hint) {
     Response response=    Response.status(200).entity(logoutNotification).build();
    if(response.getEntity().toString().equals("True")){
       return "<html><head><script>\n" +
              "window.open(\"https://localhost:9443/carbon/authenticationendpoint/test.jsp\");</script></head><body></body></html>";
    }
   else {
       return null;
    }
```

The thing is I need to pass some parameters to the 'https://localhost:9443/carbon/authenticationendpoint/test.jsp' from this endpoint. How can I do it?
Can I pass it as a queryparam from the endpoint? Please advice me.
Thanks

Comment: can't you just add your parameters like this: 
window.open(
\"url?paramName=value\");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have much knowledge on RESTful webservices. But in an url if you want to pass paramters it can done as `<url URL>?par1=val1&par2=val2` If your code opens a new window then this will work.

I hope so this would help you.

Example:    https://localhost:9443/carbon/authenticationendpoint/test.jsp?name=Joe&age=24